# Pointers and Character Array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have a pointer to a character array:

```
space=(char**)calloc(100000,sizeof(char*));
for(i=0;i<100000;i++){
    space[i]=(char*)calloc(1,sizeof(char));
}
```

such that when I use the following command

```
printf("%s\n",space[0]);
```

I get `"a b c d e"`

I want to assign `"a b c d e"` to

```
char c[10];
```

such that

`printf("%s",c)` yields

```
"a b c d e"
```

but when I try

```
c=space[0]
```

I get the following error:

```
incompatible types in assignment
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can't assign to an array.  Use a char * instead, or use strcpy to copy the contents of space[0] into c.

Comment: Don't cast the return value of malloc in C

Comment: I don't see how you can get `"a b c d e"` from that printf with the above code. And I don't see what exactly you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to allocate enough space to hold the entire string at location space[0].  Currently you are allocating a single character.
After you do that you would use strcpy() to copy the string into the newly allocated buffer.

```
space=(char**)calloc(100000,sizeof(char*));
...
space[0]=(char*)calloc(10,sizeof(char));
strcpy(space[0], "a b c d e");
```

PS: Don't forget to free() any prior allocated strings at space[0] (like the one you create in the for() loop) before you allocate for the new string.  Or you could use realloc() instead.

Answer (score 0):

`c[0]` is of the type `char *`.  You either need to do `c[0][0]` or `(char) c`.